# VTigerCRM 7.3 (opensource) Clear the user access log

Tags: php, logging, vtiger, vtigercrm

My user access log (/logs/access_ssl_log.processed) is 1.5GB and I would like to clear it down to start a fresh to reduce the size.

Can anyone advise how I clear the content within, I don't seem to be able to find any settings for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a vtiger generated log. It seems a plesk panel apache log. I suggest you activate the rotate of the log.

You can see the instructions here: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213961605-Why-does-log-rotation-not-work-in-Plesk-